# Array - Remove records with the value zero

Tags: php, arrays

i got an array i would like to remove all records where [quantity] => 0

```
 Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [is_sub] => 0 [product] => Town [quantity] => 0 [price] => [total_item_price] => 0 [comments] => ) 

 [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [is_sub] => 0 [product] => City [quantity] => 0 [price] => [total_item_price] => 0 [comments] => ) 
 )

 [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [is_sub] => 0 [product] => News [quantity] => 1 [price] => [total_item_price] => 0 [comments] => ) 
 )
```

thanks for your help

Comment: which language are you using? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Tell us in which language you are working.

Comment: That looks like PHP `print_r()` format.

Comment: Consider using [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: its taking values from  $ids=$_SESSION['online_ids']; i would like to remove record matched with quantity 0

Comment: the array value is as above in main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll presume it's PHP.

You could do:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($value['quantity'] < 1) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

or

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($val) {
    return ($val['quantity'] > 0);
});
```

Comment: It also requires to reindex array to make its length actual. `$arr = array_values($arr);`

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_filter`:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($x) {
    return $x['quantity'] != 0;
});
```